# Kubernetes with calico

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, datastage, calico

We are trying to set up IBM Datastage container makes use of two components Docker and Kubernetes. IBM used Kubernetes with Calico (pure IP networking fabric) as networking. IBM uses ansible + shell script to set up the deployment of InfoSphere DataStage in a containerized environment.

After we install calico pod on 3 node not running and also kube-dns is in the creating state.

```
NAMESPACE   NAME                                    READY STATUS           RESTARTS AGE
default     docker-registry-6d46c849dc-crx6p         1/1  Running             0     2h
kube-system calico-etcd-47b9q                        1/1  Running             0     2h
kube-system calico-kube-controllers-6fb8b4d696-62xmr 1/1  Running             0     9m
kube-system calico-node-5hrpj                        1/2  CrashLoopBackOff    31    2h
kube-system calico-node-bsldv                        1/2  CrashLoopBackOff    30    2h
kube-system calico-node-qfxt4                        1/2  CrashLoopBackOff    30    2h
kube-system etcd-k8snode1                            1/1  Running             0     2h
kube-system kube-apiserver-k8snode1.luc...           1/1  Running             0     2h
kube-system kube-controller-manager-k8s...           1/1  Running             0     2h
kube-system kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-k6szc                 0/3  ContainerCreating   0     2h
kube-system kube-proxy-92869                         1/1  Running             0     2h
kube-system kube-proxy-pbpc4                         1/1  Running             0     2h
kube-system kube-proxy-sd5w5i                        1/1  Running             0     2h
kube-system kube-scheduler-k8snode1                  1/1  Running             0     2h
test-1      is-en-conductor-0                        0/1  ContainerCreating   0     2h
test-1      is-engine-compute-0                      0/1  ContainerCreating   0     2h
test-1      is-servicesdocker-pod-b54c55f8c-72d62    0/1  ContainerCreating   0     2h
test-1      is-xmetadocker-pod-68774595cb-crbwl      0/1  ContainerCreating   0     2h
```

Error in creating the calico-node and kube-dns...Can anyone help us?

Comment: Hi! you have to attach some additional info like: `kubectl -n kube-system describe po <pod_name_with_error>`. Also you might need to show logs from calico Pod's containers, here is the command: `kubectl -n kube-system logs <pod_name> -c <container_name>`

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the PodCidr doesn't match `192.168.0.0/16` which is what Calico needs. This is doesn't guarantee that it will fix your problem, but in any case you can change it in your `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yml`:

```
...
containers:
- command:
  - kube-controller-manager
  - --address=127.0.0.1
  - --allocate-node-cidrs=true
  - --cloud-provider=aws
  - --cluster-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 <== Here.
...
```

Then edit the `ConfigMap` for your `kube-proxy`

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap kube-proxy
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.conf: |-
    apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
    bindAddress: 0.0.0.0
    clientConnection:
      acceptContentTypes: ""
      burst: 10
      contentType: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf
      kubeconfig: /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf
      qps: 5
    clusterCIDR: 192.168.0.0/16 <== change this
    configSyncPeriod: 15m0s
    ...
```

Then restart all the servers in your cluster.

Hope it helps.